# Automatic Sales Tax in 4D

Tags: 4d-database, sales-tax

I'm hoping there is a soul out there who has some experience with 4D SAS. We use it for our inventory/sales management. What I am struggling with now is how to set up some sort of system to automatically calculate sales tax within our own state etc.

**Edited:**
Currently we sell products in CA and we are required to adjust sales tax based on the locations of certain orders. We take orders online and that part is easy, currently WooCommerce can integrate with TaxJar or solutions like that to address our needs.

Any phone/fax/mail order however we input directly into 4D. This is where I am struggling. Currently when we have any of these orders, we have to then declare taxes at a later date etc.

What I am trying to do is set up either my own database (I think?) or what I would prefer to do, is have some external service integrate directly with 4d that would automatically calculate the necessary sales tax and include that in our totals.

So to TLDR my questions: 
1) Is there an automatic 3rd party solution that I can integrate with 4d that will automatically calculate sales tax? If so does anybody have any experience in doing so?
2) If not, is there the ability to build a manual database of tax rates (based on zip codes for example) that can be implemented into 4D. If so does anybody have any experience in doing so?

If there is some sort of database entry that anybody is aware of or that someone can guide me to that would be much appreciated, and/or if anybody has experience with this specific issue and knows what to do that also would  be great! Hope that helps clarify!

Comment: Your question doesn't really meet the format expected here on StackOverflow and could be interpreted as requesting opinion based suggestions. However I tried to answer you anyways without any opinion based suggestions. You may want to reword your question to be more clear about what you have already tried and what your actual problem is. It is always best if you can include a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Comment: I think Tim is on the right track with the web services integration. I don't know of any 4D plugins or components that handle sales tax, but that isn't really my area work. Do you have a technical question?

Comment: Thanks guys, I modified the question to hopefully be more specific!

Answer (score 1):

TaxJar or ZipTax both offer APIs that 4D can use to do lookups. IMO, REST is the way to go. I've integrated 4D with WooCommerce as well.

Comment: I am going to look into that. I have a feeling its too large of a question to ask how you did that? However I would love the help.

Comment: I can certainly help. How can we connect?

Answer (score 0):

4D has a built-in [Web Services (SOAP) Client](http://livedoc.4d.com/4Dv16/help/Title/en/page45.html) so you could utilize any [online API](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+api+sales+tax) that has a [SOAP](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+api+sales+tax+soap) endpoint.

4D also has built-in [HTTP Client](http://livedoc.4d.com/4Dv16/help/Title/en/page2601.html) commands so you could also utilize any [online API](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+api+sales+tax) that has a [REST](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+api+sales+tax+rest) endpoint.

Comment: Thank you Tim! I think that sent me down the correct path! Is there any documentation that you might have? You are a 4D Dev so is there any advantage or disadvantage for using REST or SOAP?